# Javascript Function Removal and Replacement

Tags: javascript, ajax, mailto

My site is AJAX based so I have an `window.onbeforeunload = function(){};`. However, I have mailto link and when I click those mailto links, the confirm reload pops up, which I don't like. Is there a way to write a function to remove the `window.onbeforeunload = function(){};`, pull up the mail editor from the mailto link, and then put the `window.onbeforeunload = function(){};` back?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using pure JS or also a framework?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script like this after your anchor:

```
<a href="mailto: example@address.com">Mail</a>
<script>
  (function(w, d){
    var anchors = d.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var a = anchors[anchors.length - 1];

    a.onclick = function(){
      var old_unload = w.onbeforeunload;
      w.onbeforeunload = null;

      w.location = a.href;

      setTimeout(function(){
        w.onbeforeunload = old_unload;
      }, 0);

      return false;
    };

  })(window, document);
</script>
```

[### JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/nM9P9/)

Note: The first revision did not work, because `w.onbeforeunload = old_unload` was running before the browser changed to the `mailto` page. Using `setTimeout` to make the assignment asynchronous solves that problem.